# Difficulties with background-image property

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap and I would like to simply change the .jumbotron background to an image instead of the default color. I tried using "background-image: url("img/ponder.jpg");" and it's not working for some reason. I have tried using it with and without the quotation marks, and I've even tried placing the image in the root folder.. still no luck.

Here is a picture of my file structure (Root Folder): 
https://i.gyazo.com/1cf9dcfd20224c4fce8fe4a775863ab1.png

And here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at pharetra eros, vel condimentum nunc. Vivamus eget bibendum mauris. Integer quis volutpat enim. Duis id lorem feugiat, mattis sapien eget, luctus eros. Pellentesque vestibulum tempus elit, sit amet luctus purus dictum vitae. Suspendisse non aliquam augue. Morbi sagittis mi at turpis luctus pretium. Vestibulum sit amet orci orci.</p>
        <button type=button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">About Us</button>
    </div>              
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(img/ponder.jpg);
}
```

Here's a link to the image I'm trying to display:

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?q=80&fm=jpg&s=c895a1f219d174952415b9b7a0811e62

If anybody has any ideas as to what I should try, please let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: URLs in CSS are relative to the path of the CSS – so your URL is just wrong in this case, `img/ponder.jpg` would be referring to a folder `img` _inside_ your `css` folder. You need to go one folder up, or reference from the domain root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the link works. Maybe the path you are referring to is wrong.Try using ../img/ponder.jpg

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?q=80&fm=jpg&s=c895a1f219d174952415b9b7a0811e62);
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue and I appreciate the clarification CBroe.                                Thank you both

Comment: What does the 2 dots before /img mean?

Comment: I think it means that we go back one directory so we can proceed to the image folder and grab the "ponder.jpg" image. I'm not sure why some people use quotes in their url and others don't but I'll just keep using them.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is just incorrect. You have to put the full folder path if it isnt in the same directory as your css. Your css is correctly written just not the url path.

```
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?q=80&fm=jpg&s=c895a1f219d174952415b9b7a0811e62);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkkrzokg/

Answer (score -1):

I made a small demo :

[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ttz2un1d/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <button type=button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">About Us</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 768px
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?q=80&fm=jpg&s=c895a1f219d174952415b9b7a0811e62');
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```